# ListBox with CheckBoxes based on enum

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, listbox

I want to create listbox with checkboxes based on Enum. My Enum contains flags. Now, if some checbox become chcecked/unchecked, i want to add/sub value associated with that checkbox.  ViewModel contains property that should store current value sum of flags.
How to subscribe to checked/unchecked event and how to get value that checkbox contains.

Here is the code:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <self:NewUserViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>
<Page.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="permEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="enums:Permissions"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}">
<ListBox x:Name="PermissionLbox" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource permEnum}}" Height="75" Margin="10,117,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding .}"></CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[Flags]
public enum WeekDays
{
    Sunday = 1,
    Monday = 2,
    Tuesday = 4,
    Wednesday = 8,
    Thursday = 16,
    Friday = 32,
    Saturday = 64
}`
```

Add all enum types to list itemsource

```
list.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(WeekDays));
```

Check checked checkbox:

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
    var dc = checkBox.DataContext;
    var actualValue = (WeekDays)Enum.Parse(typeof(WeekDays), dc.ToString());
    int Value += (int)actualValue;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two-way binding with the property of your `ViewModel`. Bind that property to the CheckBox.

Comment: But if i set two of checkboxes than there will be only one flag inside the propery. instead that i want to store sum of them.